# Create a custom button with icon in a custom group for Outlook using C# VSTO

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon, visual-studio-designer

I am fairly new to C# as well as the Outlook Library.

I have created a custom group in Meeting Tab of Outlook, which has a button in it.
I also added an image in properties of Button(as displayed in the screenshot).

[image]

The image would represent the logo of my add-in. But I'm not able to change the size of that image.

I want my button to look similar to that of other buttons of Outlook just like 'Skype Meeting' or 'Meeting Notes' with the larger icon.

Can anyone please suggest me the way to design the Button with large icon.

I have created the Ribbon (Visual Designer) in Visual Studio 2015 for Outlook 2016 Add-In using VSTO. What would be the best way to do this using C#?

Answer (score 1):

There are two sizes for "button" ribbon control:

```
size="large"
size="normal"
```

If you add into your button control XML large size, you'll get the button look you are referring to. For more information on how to customize Office Fluent Ribbon please refer to the following great resources:

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as I mentioned, I'm using Ribbon (Visual Designer)  and not Ribbon (XML). Please tell me the way, that how can I do it using Visual Designer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this problem. 
We can set the property 'ControlSize' of Button to 'RibbonControlSizeLarge'.

Comment: Your answer related to usage of Visual Designer of Visual Studio IDE, I have added proper tag into your question. I would also suggest to get closer look at IDE you are using, before start to code. every coder should know his tools ;)

Comment: Yes Definitely! I'll look into IDE more. Thank you for your suggestion!